# I want to exclude empty category from Mage::getModel in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, getmodel

```
$allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1')
->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')
->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId))
->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
```

Currently, this code showing all category including empty category I want to remove empty category from collection

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active', 1)
    ->setLoadProductCount(true);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getProductCount();
}
```

Comment: Think `$categories->setLoadProductCount(true);` is a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

> You can remove empty categories from category collection

```
foreach($allCats as $key => $category) {
    if ($category->getProductCount() === 0) {
        $allCats->removeItemByKey($category->getId());
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Not possible to check without loop/outside the loop?, Can directly exclude from the collection ?

Comment: I don't know the way of excluding categories from collection without loop. I think using loop it may be the way to exclude the categories from collection not delete it.